# How do you generate random variables according to a given continuous probability density function?

Tags: python, random, normal-distribution, probability-density

I'm trying to generate random variables according to three different probability density functions. Two of the functions are scaled normal distributions, `µ = 260/3, σ = 100/3, scaled by 1.53666351546` and `µ = 854/9, σ = 100/3, scaled by 1.78979465778` respectively, and the third is the sum of eleven different normal distributions and two half-normal distributions.

I tried messing with transforming the `numpy.random.randn` function for the first two distributions, but I couldn't get the maths to line up. I'm yet to try anything for the third distribution, because I don't even know where to start.

Using the code created by sato in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59939092/generating-random-numbers-from-custom-continuous-probability-density-function), I was able to modify it with Peter O.'s answer to get the following code for my first distribution:

```py
from decimal import Decimal
from scipy import stats
import numpy

Q = Decimal(0.0460999054638)/((Decimal(2)*Decimal(numpy.pi))**Decimal(0.5))

class Distribution_B(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x):
        return (Q*Decimal(numpy.exp(-(((Decimal(260)-Decimal(3)*Decimal(x))**Decimal(5))/Decimal(20000)))))

distribution = Distribution_B(a = 0, b = 100)
distribution.rvs()
```

However, when I ran the code, I encountered the following error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "[numpy function_base library]", line 2411
    outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in _cdf_single (vectorized)
```

Edit: I ran the code without changing anything except variable names, and it seems that the error only happens sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from decimal import Decimal
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

Q = Decimal(0.0460999054638) / ((Decimal(2) * Decimal(np.pi)) ** Decimal(0.5))

class Distribution_B(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x):
        x = float(x)  # Convert x to float
        return Q * Decimal(np.exp(-(((Decimal(260) / Decimal(3) - Decimal(x)) ** Decimal(2)) / (2 * (Decimal(100) / Decimal(3)) ** Decimal(2)))))

distribution = Distribution_B(a=0, b=100)
samples = distribution.rvs(size=1000)
```

**Remember to adjust the size on the next line**
[image: Here is the resulting samples]

Comment: Would adding distributions together be as simple as doing "return Distribution_B + Distribution_A" after defining the two distributions?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you need to perform a convolution of their probability density functions. If you are having trouble if you create a new question for that spesific question, and copy the link of it as a comment here I will be happy to help you out.